# (Why) Is the $n$-dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$ unique?

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-algebras

One constructs an $n$-dimensional irreducible representation for $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$ as follows: $\rho(h) = \text{diag}(n-1,n-3,\ldots,-n+3,-n+1), \rho(e) =  \text{uppdiag}(n-1,n-2,\ldots,1), \rho(f) = \text{lowdiag}(1,2,\ldots,n-1)$, where 'uppdiag' refers to the diagonal "one up" from the diagonal in 'diag', and 'lowdiag' defined similarly.

My question is: is this the only irreducible, $n$-dimensional representation for $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$? If so, why? Can one invoke the correspondence between Lie group and algebras for a simply connected lie group, along with the fact that $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ has a unique $n$-dimensional representation? Could one somehow use the fact that $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ has a unique irreducible $n$-dimensional representation?

A reference to the result would also be appreciated... I could only seem to find results on $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: No, there are many $n$-dimensional representations for it, but they could be equivalent, like in the complex case.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I guess what I'm asking is whether there is only one 'equivalence class' of these representations - i.e. does this result for the complex case carry over to the real case? why/why not? (I'm not too sure exactly what equivalence relation I mean here... probably change of basis...)

Comment: Equivalent means isomorphic as Lie algebra modules. So a module homomorphism which is bijective.

Comment: So what do all the 'equivalent' representations of the one given in the question look like (as matrices, say)? If I'm understanding, an isomorphism $\phi$ has to be a vector space isomorphism, and must respect the Lie algebra action. As a vector space isomorphism, it maps one basis of the vector space onto another. To respect the Lie algebra action, we must have $\rho(h)\phi(v) = \phi(\rho(h)v)$ etc.This seems to suggest that potentially not every change of basis for the matrices $\rho(h)$ etc yields an equivalent representation... this doesn't seem right... what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: in some sense don't we have to fix a basis in the first place in order to make sense of these actions?